# With gcc, include strictly C99 symbols, specifically excluding POSIX

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

I am taking a course in C after many years programming. My instructor is not using a POSIX machine, and I was recently penalized for using the `index` function in an assignment. I did some research and I notice that while `index` was an early part of AT&T Unix and is POSIX-compliant, it is not part of the C99 standard. *I'd like gcc to help me find use of similar symbols*. I am compiling on OSX with gcc 4.2 (*not* llvm)

My first leg of research involved noticing that my string.h file wraps the prototype for `index` in the following check for feature test macros:

```
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
```

After a little digging, I found this (in my `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h`):

```
 /* STRICT  Defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE or _XOPEN_SOURCE restricts the
 *      available APIs to exactly the set of APIs defined by the
 *      corresponding standard, based on the value defined.
 *
 *      A correct, portable definition for _POSIX_C_SOURCE is 200112L.
 *      A correct, portable definition for _XOPEN_SOURCE is 600L.
 */
```

And so with this gcc command:

```
gcc -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -o myExec ./mySource.c
```

I *do* get a decent warning:

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘index’
```

This confuses me, *and* I want to make the program fail to link as well. The reason it confuses me is, I read [at opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html) that defining that macro should **expose** POSIX symbols, not hide them. So here is my question in a succinct form:

**How can I make gcc 4.2 (on OSX 10.6) compile and link my program in an environment which is *strictly* C99 with *no additional symbols* available?**

Ideally, I want **warnings during compile and failure to link**. I'm hoping that the answer does not involve telling gcc that I *am* writing POSIX code, when I believe that's the opposite of what I want to tell it. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Are you really stuck to gcc 4.2? Because this isn't even completely conforming to C99 itself. Clang might be a better choice.

Comment: No, by no means! I'm willing to try new compilers (I have been using clang/llvm on a newer OSX for other projects). Perhaps I'll report on that tomorrow.

Comment: `index` isn't exactly 'POSIX-compliant'. It's removed in POSIX 2008, and already deprecated in POSIX 2001.

Comment: The problem may be specifying both `-ansi` and `-std=c99`. `-ansi` is equvialent to specifying `-std=c89`. I am not sure of behaviour of gcc when asked to adhere to two different standards, but `-ansi` and `-std=c99` appear to be mutually exclusive options.

Comment: @hmjd thanks, and good eye (evidence of trying many options). If I understand many GNU tools correctly, specifying multiple flags with contradictory meaning is usually resolved simply by adhering to the last one. Though I will remove the -ansi (and verify the results are the same before editing the post)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You're not going to get a link error, sorry.  Libraries don't work that way.  The `index` function *is* a part of the standard library.  The standard library supports multiple versions of C (and POSIX) at the same time, and the macros select which prototypes get exposed.
2. The `-ansi` flag is equivalent to `-std=c89`, so stop doing that.
3. You are right that `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` exposes additional functionality, but it also specifies *which version* of the functionality to expose.  Defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` means that `index` appears in `<strings.h>` instead of `<string.h>`.  It's still there.  Specifying the 2008 POSIX will get rid of `index` entirely, since it was removed from later versions of the POSIX standard.
4. There *is* a macro which means "only ANSI C", and that is `_ANSI_SOURCE`.
5. You can get a compilation error (but not a link error) by adding `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration`.

```
$ gcc -Werror-implicit-function-declaration \
    -D_ANSI_SOURCE -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 ...
error: implicit declaration of function 'index'
```

This seems to work just fine on all combinations OS X 10.5/10.8, GCC 4.0/4.2.

Comment: +1 - nice summary of a practical approach that will cover most of the non ISO C functionality (and that might be sufficient for ctrahey's needs)

Comment: Great answer!  I didn't know about `_ANSI_SOURCE`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! That'll do for my purposes just fine :-)

Comment: There is `_ISOC99_SOURCE`, what does make it differ?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a C99 environment, pass the flags `-std=c99 -pedantic` to gcc.  This should not define any additional feature-test macros.

Note however that this is only omits the *declarations*, because those invade the C99 programmer-reserved namespace.  The actual symbols are still likely to be available - those shouldn't affect the compilation of a correct C99 program because they tend to be "weak" symbols, but they won't force an error if you declare them yourself and use them.

Comment: Sorry for omitting it at first (I have edited my question to indicate this), but I have been using these flags; they do not cause the warning (without the POSIX feature macro), and also do not cause link failure (even with the macro)

Answer (score 1):

For the record: with **`icc`** I found it most helpful to do

```
icc -no-gcc -diag-enable port-win -fabi-version=2 -std=c99 ...
```

which will skip all gcc specific voodoo in the system header files and warn about POSIXisms that don't exist on windows.

As for throwing an error, I'd just use `-Werror`.

Unfortunately, gcc can't turn off gnu-specific attribute processing in system header files.  And, even more unfortunate, the stated gcc version does not support the `-Werror=<diagnostic>` syntax to throw errors upon certain warnings only.

So in essence, the combination of compiler and version you state can't really help you with what you want.

Comment: `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` is at least as old as GCC 4.0.

Comment: ah, I see, I meant the new syntax: `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration,...`