# Force C99 Compliant Compilation in clang

Tags: c, clang

I am trying to write some C99 code that needs to [compile on solaris  in c99 mode](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/Rconfig/r-patched-solaris-x86), but I don't have access to a solaris machine.  Instead, I'm trying to do this on OSX with `clang`.  However, using (file min.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", (int) strnlen("hello world", 5));
  return 0;
}
```

I don't get any errors or warnings about `strnlen`

```
$ clang -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra min.c
$ ./a.out
5
```

even though [`strnlen` is a 2008 posix extension](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strnlen.3.html).

This with:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Is there any way to get `clang` to strictly conform to c99 so that I have a better chance at portability wrt solaris?

Comment: Conforming does not mean that you cant use any function you want. You have it in the library, you have the prototype in the `h` file so it is 100% fine to compile & link without any warnings.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I need to get my paws on the same library the machine I'm having compatibility issues with (solaris) is building against.

Comment: @PeterJ_01-- `strnlen()` is not part of the Standard library, although `strnlen_s()` is in Annex K. The Standard says that ["a strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p5)

Comment: @David Bowling It is one of the nonsenses in this document. It actually disallows use of any (even written by you for the particular project) libraries. You can write any function with any name yourself. If you write `strnlen()` in your program you think the compiler should produce an error or warning? Of course not.

Comment: @PeterJ_01-- this is just the definition of _strict conformance_ provided by the Standard. This is what OP seems to be asking about. And when you write your own functions, if they only use strictly conforming features of  the language, your program is strictly conforming....

Comment: He's also asking about visibility of functions. That is not part of the compiler but rather libc.  In the case of OS X, libsystem has the kitchen sink in it.  

Visibility is controlled by defining headers to turn on certain posix standards, BSD visibility and so on.  While I haven't looked at OS X headers in some time, I assume that they must set bsd visible and use similar visibility rules to freebsd due to the use of BSD userland stuff. Because of this, it's extremely loose compared to Solaris or Linux. This is not the compiler's fault.

Comment: It appears FreeBSD fixed this in 2013. Apple may not be in sync. You could write it in a VM. Get one of the open source forks of solaris and use that. https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/include/string.h?r1=265877&r2=265878&

Comment: Strictly speaking, clang (like gcc) is a freestanding implementation, it does not provide the libraries, only few headers (the ones required for a freestanding implementation plus `stdatomic.h`. So this is about your standard library, not the compiler.

Comment: @David Bowling so use strictly conforming standard library. That's all. if you use one not conforming - it is your problem, compiler actually does not know anything abut the libraries. of course you can put as many `#if`s and #error's as you need hiding not conforming prototypes and displaying errors for your liking.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as a conforming compiler or a conforming standard library. A compiler and a library are two of the components that can make up a conforming implementation. Those two components not only have to be correct, they have to work together correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@DietrichEpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930144/with-gcc-include-strictly-c99-symbols-specifically-excluding-posix/11930770#11930770), the following seems to work:

```
clang -std=c99 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L min.c
min.c:5:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strnlen' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("%d\n", (int) strnlen("hello world", 5));
                       ^
  1 warning generated.
```

The [standards man page appears to support this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/standards.7.html):

> POSIX.1-2001 is aligned with C99, so that all of the library functions standardized in C99 are also standardized in POSIX.1-2001.

This produces the desired outcome on OSX 10.12.6 with Xcode and clang.

Answer (score 4):

You *might* have a non-conforming implementation, most likely due to a header problem, or a mismatch between your compiler and headers.

On my system (Ubuntu 17.04, x86_64, clang 4.0.0) I get:

```
$ clang -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra min.c
min.c:5:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strnlen' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("%d\n", (int) strnlen("hello world", 5));
                       ^
1 warning generated.
$
```

But `strnlen`, though it's not defined by the C standard, is a reserved identifier.  All identifiers starting with `str`, `wcs`, or `mem` followed by a lowercase letter are reserved when `<string.h>` is included.

C99 7.1.3p2 says:

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which
>   it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

**UPDATE :** As M.M's comment correctly points out, your program does not declare or define `strnlen`; it merely refers to it. I'll have to think about the implications.

Since your program has undefined behavior (maybe), a conforming implementation is not required to diagnose it. It would certainly be more user-friendly for your compiler to warn you about this, but its failure to do so does not make it non-conforming.

If you were using an identifier that's not reserved, the compiler would be required to diagnose it. For example, the `stpcpy` function is also a POSIX extension, but its name is not reserved. If this program compiles with no warnings or errors with `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char s[10];
    stpcpy(s, "hello");
    puts(s);
}
```

then you have grounds to complain.

Comment: Thanks Keith, the issue seems to be be that my standard library on OSX is of the "kitchen sink" variety, and I don't have a good way to exclude the POSIX.1 extensions from it when compiling with clang.  In my case, `strnlen` actually is in <string.h>...

Comment: The program doesn't declare or define `strnlen` though. In C99 calling an undeclared function is a constraint violation; it does not implicitly declare the function like C89 did.  (Also I am unconvinced that in C89 mode, this implicit declaration would count for causing UB due to declaring a reserved identifier).

Comment: @M.M: Quite right. I've updated my answer accordingly, and I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: I'm leaning towards saying the implementation is non-conforming by failing to issue a diagnostic for use of the undeclared function;  however I think there is some merit to interpreting the standard as allowing the implementation to declare other identifiers in the reserved space.

Comment: Also, fwiw, I clarified the question a little bit (i.e. I need to produce c99 compliant code for later compilation on solaris, but my osx lib includes posix.1 extensions and possibly more that aren't kosher there).

Comment: @M.M: It would in many cases be impractical to design an implementation which didn't declare anything in the reserved space, at least within its own headers.  Unless an implementation has special "magic" to suppress some [but not all!] diagnostics within macro expansions, requiring use of reserved identifiers to trigger diagnostics would seem unhelpful.